# Using lxml's Target Parser Method on an HTML Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm primarily a c++ programmer but am trying to do some web scraping in Python, and plan to write a script that determines the most-used word on a web page using `lxml`. To do this as efficiently as possible, I would like to not actually build the element tree, but parse through the page and insert each word into a hash table.

In trying to skip building the tree, however, I'm running into several errors. Right now my console is saying

```
'lxml.etree.HTMLParser' object is not iterable.
```

Here is my code (copying much of it from the `lxml` introduction page):

```
# classes
class ParserTarget: 
    events = []
    close_count = 0
    def start(self, tag, attrib): 
        self.events.append(("start", tag, attrib))
    def end(self): 
        events, self.events = self.events, []
        self.close_count += 1
        return events

website = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Mosley"
opened = urlopen(website)

parserTarget = ParserTarget()
parser = etree.HTMLParser(target=parserTarget)
events = etree.iterparse(opened, parser, html=True, recover=True)
print(parser_target.close_count)
```

Am I missing something, or is there a better method to do what I need? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what errors ? add it in question.

Comment: Sorry about that- I'm currently seeing an 'lxml.etree.HTMLParser' object is not iterable error. I've added that to the question!

Comment: always add full error message (traceback). There are other usefull information - ie. which like makes problem. It helps to find solution without running code :) Or create small, working example which everyone can copy-paste and run and see problem.